# Passing and using a Class type in a method in Java

Tags: java, class, types, methods, parameter-passing

I have a parser method which will fill a user defined collection type upon completion. I am trying to abstract this class in my abstract parser class.

Here is the code

```
    protected List<Collection> parseData(List<Data> data, Class<Collection> collectionType)
    {
        List<Collection> parsedData = new ArrayList<collectionType>();
        //Parse data
        return parsedData
    }
```

However I keep getting the following errors on the list instantiation line:
    collectionType cannot be resolved to a type, 
    ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

This is my first time trying something like this and I am not sure what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should note as I just wish to emphasize, that the Collection is not the Java Collection class, but rather an interface for classes that I defined.

Comment: -1 for naming your class `Collection`

Comment: Show your full class (with imports...)

Comment: can `Collection` be any type at all? how can you put `data` into it if you don't know what type it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use generic method. Something like this.

C# :

```
    protected List<T> parseData<T>(List<Data> data, T collectionType)
    {
        List<T> parsedData = new List<T>();
        //Parse data
        return parsedData;
    }
```

JAVA :

```
protected <T> List<T> callFriend(List<Data> data, Class<T> collectionType) {
     List<T> parsedData = new ArrayList<T>();
        //Parse data
        return parsedData;
}
```

Comment: Based on Google, is is my understanding that this is for C#, I am looking to do this in Java

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention before that you need in Java. I've added Java version.

Comment: "java" is one of the tags.. :)

Comment: _Bugari_ ,  before there was not this tag

Comment: That was my fault, added after the fact, not realizing I had missed it. And that did the trick, so thanks for the help!

Comment: **newacct**, I think _Eddie Du Vall_  want to do some manipulations with collectionType argument while he parse data in body of this method. For example he can check if collectionType has attribute that equals to some value. So, it is he add it to parseData list or anything else.